# How to open email app on mobile device using react native without package?

Tags: javascript, react-native

i want to make some button to open email app on mobile device (android/ios) but i don't want to use any package. this is only opens the email app not sends an email, can this be done in react native?

Comment: If you're looking to do it on iOS and Android, your best bet is likely to be using a package. Otherwise you may have to write your logic twice. I know you don't want a package, but maybe at least this will help you start to find the right approach: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/

Answer (score 3):

React-Native Mail function.

```
Linking.openURL('mailto:support@example.com')
```

It's react-native in-built component **Linking** you can use.
You can also add subject and body.